# creating full range of random floats using std::random

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I'm attempting to test a mathematical class I've created using random numbers from the full range of representable positive`float`s, but I find that I seem to be having a problem with my use of `std::random`.  This program

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
class Rand {
public:
    Rand(T lo=std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), 
         T hi=std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) : 
        r(bind(std::uniform_real_distribution<>(lo, hi),std::mt19937_64{})) {}
    T operator()() const { return r(); }
private:
    std::function<T()> r;
};

int main()
{
    Rand<float> f{};
    const int samples = 1000000;
    float min = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    float max = std::numeric_limits<float>::min();
    std::cout << "range min = " << max 
        << ", max = " << min << '\n';
    for (int i=0; i < samples; ++i) {
        float r = f();
        if (r < min) min = r;
        if (r > max) max = r;
    }
    std::cout << "for n = " << samples 
        << "\nsample min = " << min 
        << ", max = " << max << std::endl;
}
```

produces this output

```
range min = 1.17549e-38, max = 3.40282e+38
for n = 1000000
sample min = 8.14884e+31, max = 3.40281e+38
```

Clearly the range is extremely skewed toward larger numbers.  How do I generate the desired range of `float`s with a uniform distribution?

Comment: I think this isn't "skewed" toward lager numbers. There are O( 10E31 ) numbers below 8.14884e+31, but O( 10E38 ) between this min and 3.40281e+38. Do you want a uniform distribution of exponents?

Comment: The seed is the default value of 5489u as defined by the standard.

Comment: Ok, so this is intended? I would run those tests with a different seed each time, because it many weird things might happen for one specific (fixed) seed.

Comment: Yes, it's intended.  For the tests to be repeatable, a fixed seed is used -- it may as well be the default.

Comment: Perhaps I do want uniform distribution of exponents.  For these tests, I want some large and some small numbers, so I suppose I could use `T operator()() const { return exp(r()); }` and adjust the limits via `log`.

Comment: I think you can also use a `std::exponential_distribution`, though I found it a bit hard to properly set up, since it doesn't allow adjusting the min and max values (sometimes returns inf) and the parameter might be tricky to choose. Nevertheless, I think it expresses the intent better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the statistics you have printed out, I've computed both the theoretical and actual mean, variance, skew and kurtosis of [this distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29).  Here is my code, and the results:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <cmath>

template <typename T>
class Rand {
public:
    Rand(T lo=std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), 
         T hi=std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) : 
        r(bind(std::uniform_real_distribution<>(lo, hi),std::mt19937_64{})) {}
    T operator()() const { return r(); }
private:
    std::function<T()> r;
};

template <class T>
inline
T
sqr(T x)
{
    return x * x;
}

int main()
{
    Rand<float> f{};
    const int samples = 1000000;
    float min = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    float max = std::numeric_limits<float>::min();
    std::vector<float> u;
    std::cout << "range min = " << max 
        << ", max = " << min << '\n';
    for (int i=0; i < samples; ++i) {
        float r = f();
        if (r < min) min = r;
        if (r > max) max = r;
        u.push_back(r);
    }
    std::cout << "for n = " << samples 
        << "\nsample min = " << min 
        << ", max = " << max << std::endl;
    double mean = std::accumulate(u.begin(), u.end(),
                                          double(0)) / u.size();
    double var = 0;
    double skew = 0;
    double kurtosis = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < u.size(); ++i)
    {
        double d = (u[i] - mean);
        double d2 = sqr(d);
        var += d2;
        skew += d * d2;
        kurtosis += d2 * d2;
    }
    var /= u.size();
    double dev = std::sqrt(var);
    skew /= u.size() * dev * var;
    kurtosis /= u.size() * var * var;
    kurtosis -= 3;
    double x_mean = ((double)min + max) / 2;
    double x_var = sqr((double)max - min) / 12;
    double x_skew = 0;
    double x_kurtosis = -6./5;
    std::cout << std::scientific << '\n';
    std::cout << "            expected        actual\n";
    std::cout << "mean      " << x_mean     << "       " << mean << "\n";
    std::cout << "variance  " << x_var      << "       " << var << "\n";
    std::cout << "skew      " << x_skew     << "       " << skew << "\n";
    std::cout << "kurtosis  " << x_kurtosis << "       " << kurtosis << "\n";
}
```

And here are the results:

```
range min = 1.17549e-38, max = 3.40282e+38
for n = 1000000
sample min = 8.14884e+31, max = 3.40281e+38

            expected        actual
mean      1.701407e+38       1.700724e+38
variance  9.649275e+75       9.645774e+75
skew      0.000000e+00       7.401975e-04
kurtosis  -1.200000e+00       -1.199432e+00
```

Everything is looking pretty good to me.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful.  It seems the problem was actually my imprecise thinking about a uniform distribution rather than a coding issue as @dyp first mentioned and you have now confirmed.

Comment: +1 but note that the [Boost.Accumulators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/accumulators.html) library can compute all those stats for you *with only a single pass over the data*. [Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab45c2227b88d607) that reproduces your results.

Answer (score -1):

The biggest point you are missing is that you are not generating numbers between (-max_value,max_value) , but between ( 0 ,max_value).

There are about pow(10,32) numbers between 0 and 8.14884e+31, but there are about pow(10,37) numbers between 8.14884e+31 and 3.40281e+38. Hence the result is obvious.

Comment: OP wants to produce positive floats. I agree with the second point (see my comment to the OP).